# Authentication from Rest service and Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, rest, security

I'm developping an hybrid application with Cordova and AngularJs witch consume services provided by a REST web service. I'm beginner with this kind of project and I look for a simple example of authentication.

I searched on the net but I cant't find a simple tutorial to follow.

can anyone healp me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing the REST API youself? In that case an easy way to set up authentication is to use JSON Web Tokens (JWT). Check out http://www.jwt.io for more information. You could use the [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) library to handle the client side stuff, they even have example implementations for the server side.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks @DrDumbom, I'm using Spring REST and I want  to authenticate users existing in database so I have to maintain session. I don't think that Jwt allows to do that

Comment: Why wouldn't it? One of the major points of using token is to not having to maintain sessions and do database lookups for every single request. You still store the user information in the database,